# Get string range in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to do a query with Lambda expression to get values where result set is between a certain range. The value type string in the database and is used to store date values.
In SQL the between operator works with this values but not with Lambda expression. I have used this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213956/need-lambda-expression-orderby-with-datetime-conversion) for guidance.

### Code:

```
IQueryable<BankmedStatments> q = db.BankmedStatments.Where(u => DateTime.Parse(u.fServiceDate) >= DateTime.Parse(newStartDate));
```

### Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197956/compare-datetime-as-a-string-into-a-linq-to-entities-doesnt-recognize-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SqlFunctions.DateDiff(String, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check date difference on server side:

```
IQueryable<BankmedStatments> q = 
  db.BankmedStatments.Where(u => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ms", u.fServiceDate, newStartDate) > 0);
```

In that case Entity Framework will be able to generate SQL query, which will look like:

```
 SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[fServiceDate] AS [fServiceDate]
 FROM [dbo].[BankmedStatments] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE (DATEDIFF(ms, [Extent1].[fServiceDate], @date)) > 0
```

Of course, consider to use appropriate data type to store dates in your database.

Comment: Thanks this works great with less effort at all

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that as you getting an IQueryable, the code is actually executing against the database, and is deferred.  So the problem is that SQL does not  have a method called DataTime.Parse.

Comment: How will I get it to work?

Comment: I think the aticle @Vladmir refers to is certainly one option to think about.  The problem is that your dates are exposed as strings and you are doing a DateTime.Parse on those. If you expose the properties as Dates, you can eliminate the DateTime.Parse and just use direct direct date comparison, which will work.